# Android: Layout Problems with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I must be doing this all wrong, and layouts confuse me, so I hope someone might guide me in the right direction. This whole thing is a mess because I've been fiddling with it non-stop since I created it a month ago, trying to fix little issues here and there, so I apologise quite a lot in advance for this disaster.

Literally all that I want is a `LinearLayout` where everything is centred horizontally and vertically.

This is how it shows up in my Design page.

[image]

Before I dump in my layout, allow me to explain what's going on.
I have a `TextView` that shows status messages above the `ImageButton`. Below the `ImageButton`, I have a `TextSwitcher` and finally a circular `ProgressBar`.

I've had to put `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` on my `ImageButton` because the image is much bigger than would fit, otherwise.

Anyway, here's the dump. Hoping someone might be able to make suggestions.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|center"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gesslar.threshvote.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorFaded"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textStatusMessage"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonVote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vote_button_image"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:onClick="onVotePressed"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/textCountdown"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/countdown"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use any other layout like FrameLayout.

Comment: If everything is just supposed to be center in the parent layout, why not just use a RelativeLayout, then set the gravity to center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still like using `LinearLayout`, you can order your layout like this to have a layout center both horizontally and vertically

```
    <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0ff"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Button Center Vertical/ Horizontal" />
                </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or simple use `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to have a layout center both orientation

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, LinearLayout can either store everything horizontally or vertically but not both at the same time. So you have to choose specially what do you want. If you want everything to appear in vertical fashion but still some components, say TextView needed to be in a horizontal layout, you may wish to use another LinearLayout (nested inside the main LinearLayout and give it an orientation : Horizontal ).

Apart from this, I don't think there is any problem with that Layout or I did not understand your problem properly, either one.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough, and I'm sorry. I'm looking for things to be ordered vertically, but centred both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @the_gesslar use android:gravity = "center" in the LinearLayout and also you might try with android:layout_gravity="center" only.. I actually need to run your code in my android studio to check, but I am 60% sure it's gonna work. Everything will be stored in center.